# Is $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin n|}n$ convergent？

Tags: real-analysis

Is $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin n|}n$ convergent？

It seems to be divergent to me because of this (i know that's not a proof just a thought):

$|sin(n)|\leq 1$ but for about half the values of n, $1/2<|sin(n)|$ for these values the series $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1/2}n$ diverges therefore $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin n|}n$ diverges.

Can someone give me a hint or tell me if I'm at least going in the right direction.

Thank you so much

Comment: The direction seems OK, but you are not there yet...

Comment: You have $|\sin(n)|\geq (\sin(n))^2=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\cos(2n)}{2}$

Comment: Hint: Each interval $[n\pi/2-1/2,n\pi/2+1/2]$, $n$ odd, contains an integer.

Comment: Or, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034059/covergence-test-of-sum-n-geq-1-frac-sin-nn).