# Absolute convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Study convergence of the series :
$$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\frac{\pi n}{12}}{\ln{n}}$$

Conditional convergence is easy, but I can't study absolute convergence. Can you give any ideas?

Comment: this series is not absolutely convergent. Look at the subsequence for $n \equiv 6 \mod 12$. For the absolute values of this sequence, you can bound the partial sums below by the harmonic series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same solution as e.g. here:
[Covergence test of $\sum_{n\geq 1}{\frac{|\sin n|}{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034059/covergence-test-of-sum-n-geq-1-frac-sin-nn)
$$\frac{|\sin nx|}{\ln n}\ge\frac{\sin^2nx}{\ln n}=\frac12\Bigl(\frac{1}{\ln n}-\frac{\cos(2\,nx)}{\ln n}\Bigr)$$
The 1st series diverges, the 2nd converges by Dirichlet.