# Determining the Values of $\alpha$ for Which the Series is Conditionally and Absolutely Convergent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, parametric

The task is to determine for which values of $\alpha$ is the following series is conditionally convergent and absolutely convergent. My attempt is below.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {n^{-\alpha}\cdot(\ln{n}) \cdot (\sin{n})}$$

I first noted that if $\alpha \leq 0$ then the limit is not $0$ thus we must have that $\alpha \gt 0$.

Next, I decided to check for absolute convergence. Using Dirichlet's test, it is known that the partial sums of the sine function are bounded ([see here for an example of a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108486/sx-sum-n-1-inftya-n-sinnx-a-n-is-monotonic-decreasing-a-n-to-0/108586#108586)). Thus, what remains to show is that $\dfrac {\ln{n}} {n^\alpha}$ is monotone decreasing since the limit is clearly $0$ for $\alpha\gt 0$.

I calculated the derivative:

$$f(n)=\dfrac {\ln{n}} {n^\alpha} \\ 
\therefore f'(n) = \dfrac {n^{\alpha -1}\left(1-\alpha\ln{n}\right) } {n^{2\alpha}} \tag{$*$}$$

Now,

$$f'(n)  \lt 0\iff n^{\alpha -1}\left(1-\alpha\ln{n}\right) < 0$$   since $\displaystyle{ \forall \alpha, \qquad n^{2\alpha} > 0 }$.

From $(*)$ we can see that as $n \to \infty$, the expression $\left(1-\alpha\ln{n}\right)$ will eventually become negative for all $\alpha > 0$. Thus the series is absolutely convergent for all $\alpha > 0$. I'd appreciate any feedback on whether or not this solution is valid, and if I can conclude from this that there does not exist an $\alpha$ for which the series is conditionally convergent. I have tried to think of cases I might be missing but so far have found none.

Comment: You've only proved convergence (not absolute convergence) when $\alpha>0$ since you used boudedness of the partial sums of $\sum _n \sin(n)$, not of $\sum _n |\sin(n)|$. When $\alpha >1$, it is easy to see that the series is indeed absolutely convergent. It remains to deal with the absolute convergence in the case $0<\alpha\leq 1$. Use the inequality found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1034069/66096).

Comment: @GabrielRomon Let me try that now, thanks. However, which test did you use to determine that when $\alpha > 1$ the series is absolutely convergent?

Comment: When $\alpha > 1$, drop the sine and note that $$\frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} =\frac{\ln n}{n^{(\alpha-1)/2}} \frac{1}{n^{(\alpha+1)/2}} $$ Since $\displaystyle \frac{\ln n}{n^{(\alpha-1)/2}} \to 0$, it's bounded by some constant and the comparison test applies.

Comment: Hint: Dirichlets test

Comment: @GabrielRomon I think I got it. Using that Idea, I came up with the following for $\alpha \in (0;1]$:

$$\sum _{n\geq 1} |\sin(n)| \cdot \left| \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} \right| \leq \sum_{n\geq 1} 2\cdot \left| \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} \right| $$. Since $\dfrac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} \geq \dfrac{1}{n^\alpha}$ for $n \gt e$ we have that $$\sum_{n>e} \dfrac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} \geq \sum_{n>e} \dfrac{1}{n^\alpha}$$ which diverges (p-series). Does that work?

Comment: @TheOscillator I already used Dirichlet's test in my attempt as I have indicated in the post. Could you give me more information on your hint?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Kindly see my previous comment based on the idea I got from your hint.

Comment: @E.Nole you got your inequalities mixed up. You can't conclude divergence from $\sum _{n\geq 1} |\sin(n)| \cdot \left| \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} \right| \leq \sum_{n\geq 1} 2\cdot \left| \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} \right|$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon I have fixed the mistake with the inequality like this 

$$\sum _{n\gt 1}         |\sin(n)|     \cdot   \left|       \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha}     \right|      \geq  \sum_{n \gt 1}  |\sin(1)|     \cdot   \left| \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} \right|$$ Then since $\sin(1) = const$ is a constant, we can use the comparison test argument as in the previous comment to conclude divergence. How is this now?

Comment: @E.Nole why should $\sin(n)|\geq |\sin(1)|$ hold ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon I misinterpreted the graph of $|\sin(n)|$. Okay so since we are looking at the absolute-valued sine function, and the input values are integers, we can find a lower bound since the function is periodic. So that means I need to find the infimum of $|\sin(n)|, n \in \mathbb{N}$. I've given it a bit more thought and I think I should pick a natural number closest to some multiple of $\pi$, which I found to be $22$ (by looking at the graph of $y=k\pi$) so I think the inequality should be $|\sin(n)|\geq |\sin(22)|$

Comment: No, it's not that easy. For your problem the crude lower bound found here is enough https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034059/covergence-test-of-sum-n-geq-1-frac-sin-nn/1034069#1034069

Comment: @GabrielRomon I hope I've gotten it right this time:

Using the inequality, $$\frac{|\sin n|}{n}\ge\frac{\sin^2n}{n}=\frac12\Bigl(\frac1n-\frac{\cos(2\,n)}{n}\Bigr).$$ 
We get $$\sum _{n\gt 1}         |\sin(n)|     \cdot   \left|       \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha}     \right|      \geq  \sum_{n\geq1} \left|       \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha}     \right|      - \sum_{n \geq1} \frac{\cos(2n)}{n^{\alpha}} $$

The second summand is convergent by Dirichlet's test.  The first summand is divergent for $\alpha \in (0;1]$ since $$\sum_{n>e} \dfrac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} \geq \sum_{n>e} \dfrac{1}{n^\alpha}$$

Comment: @E.Nole yes this is fine, good job.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @E.Nole In order not to leave this unanswered, I suggest you write an answer yourself.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Alright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Mr [Gabriel Romon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/66096/gabriel-romon) I was able to fill in the missing parts of the solution.

This continues from the proof in the original post, which proves that for $\alpha > 0$, the series is convergent and divergent otherwise.

Let us now check for absolute convergence:

For $\alpha > 1 $ consider $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\sin(n)| \cdot \left| \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} \right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1\cdot \left| \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} \right| $$

Now, since $\alpha > 1 $ and  $\displaystyle \frac{\ln n}{n^{(\alpha-1)/2}} \to 0 $  as $n \to \infty$ we have that

$$\dfrac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} =\dfrac{\ln n}{n^{(\alpha-1)/2}} \dfrac{1}{n^{(\alpha+1)/2}} \leq M \cdot \dfrac{1}{n^{(\alpha+1)/2}} $$

Therefore

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\sin(n)| \cdot \left| \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} \right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1\cdot \left| \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} \right| \leq M \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^{(\alpha+1)/2}}$$

The sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^{(\alpha+1)/2}}$ is convergent since $\alpha >1 $ therefore the initial sum is absolutely convergent for $\alpha > 1$.

For $\alpha \in (0;1]$ we can use the inequality
$$|\sin n|\ge\sin^2n=\frac12\left(1-\cos(2\,n)\right)$$

to get

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}   |\sin(n)|     \cdot   \left|       \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha}     \right|      \geq  \frac 12 \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|       \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha}     \right|      - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2n)}{n^{\alpha}}\right) $$

We can easily verify using Dirichlet's test that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(2n)}{n^{\alpha}}$$ is convergent for $\alpha \in (0;1]$.

As for $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|       \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} \right| \tag{$*$}$$ we can note that

$$ \sum_{n>e} \dfrac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} \geq \sum_{n>e} \dfrac{1}{n^\alpha} $$

and

$$\sum_{n>e} \dfrac{1}{n^\alpha} $$ is divergent for $\alpha \in (0;1]$

Therefore, we can conclude that the initial series is conditionally convergent for $\alpha \in (0;1]$.